# Angular 2 Universal ng2-bootstrap not working Safari

Tags: ios, angular, safari, ng2-bootstrap, angular-universal

The website I created using Angular 2 together with ng2-bootstrap and serving using Webpack and Universal has been working on Chrome without a hitch, but doesn't work on Safari or Microsoft Edge.

At the moment Safari is the most important.

In the developer console I get the following errors:

```
[Error] EXCEPTION: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
    handleError
    next
    (anonymous function)
    __tryOrUnsub
    next
    _next
    next
    next
    emit
    onError
    onHandleError
    handleError (zone.js:207)
    runTask (zone.js:139)
    invoke (zone.js:304)
[Error] ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
    handleError
    next
    (anonymous function)
    __tryOrUnsub
    next
    _next
    next
    next
    emit
    onError
    onHandleError
    handleError (zone.js:207)
    runTask (zone.js:139)
    invoke (zone.js:304)
[Error] setProperty
setElementProperty
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges
detectViewChildrenChanges
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges
detectViewChildrenChanges
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges
detectContentChildrenChanges
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges
detectContentChildrenChanges
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges
detectViewChildrenChanges
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges
detectChanges

forEach@[native code]
tick

invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:33
onInvoke
invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:202:42
run@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:96:49
runInner
run
next

__tryOrUnsub
next
_next
next
next
emit
_checkStable
onLeave
onInvokeTask
invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:235:54
runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:57
invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:40
    handleError
    next
    (anonymous function)
    __tryOrUnsub
    next
    _next
    next
    next
    emit
    onError
    onHandleError
    handleError (zone.js:207)
    runTask (zone.js:139)
    invoke (zone.js:304)
[Error] TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
    __tryOrUnsub
    next
    _next
    next
    next
    emit
    onError
    onHandleError
    handleError (zone.js:207)
    runTask (zone.js:139)
    invoke (zone.js:304)
```

This doesn't help me much as I can't find out what readonly property it is trying to assign something to.

I will be posting my progress here as I find out more.

#### Update

I have updated to the latest Angular 2 2.1.0 versions but still no luck.

I also read one another project that someone remove the "use strict"; from the project, this at at least loaded the page without any errors at all. However when I tried to click on a link the error came back.

#### Update

I finally found the actual line that is causing the error:

```
BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.setProperty = function(el, name, value) {
   el[name] = value
};
```

Is there any possible way to figure out if a property is readonly or not before setting it?

#### Update

I think I got the one error fixed. Turned out in one of my components in the template I was assigning the style property which is readonly.

So instead of `<div [style]="getStyle()">` I did `<div [attr.style]="getStyle()">` which stopped the TypeError from raising.

However, now I have another error:

```
[Error] EXCEPTION: Can't find variable: Intl
    handleError (index.js:13885:260)
    next (index.js:8825:664)
    (anonymous function) (index.js:9320:555)
    __tryOrUnsub (index.js:980:1636)
    next (index.js:980:768)
    _next (index.js:975:294)
    next (index.js:962)
    next (index.js:1316:668)
    emit (index.js:9320:179)
    onError (index.js:9572:261)
    onHandleError (index.js:20269:272)
    handleError (index.js:27565:6501)
    runTask (index.js:27565:3198)
    invoke (index.js:27567:1047)
[Error] ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
    handleError (index.js:13885:439)
    next (index.js:8825:664)
    (anonymous function) (index.js:9320:555)
    __tryOrUnsub (index.js:980:1636)
    next (index.js:980:768)
    _next (index.js:975:294)
    next (index.js:962)
    next (index.js:1316:668)
    emit (index.js:9320:179)
    onError (index.js:9572:261)
    onHandleError (index.js:20269:272)
    handleError (index.js:27565:6501)
    runTask (index.js:27565:3198)
    invoke (index.js:27567:1047)
[Error] intlDateFormat@http://localhost:3000/index.js:11996:633
http://localhost:3000/index.js:12000:513
http://localhost:3000/index.js:12000:1106
forEach@[native code]
dateFormatter@http://localhost:3000/index.js:12000:1057
format@http://localhost:3000/index.js:12000:1448
transform@http://localhost:3000/index.js:17986:940
[native code]
http://localhost:3000/index.js:6148:4063
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19974:507
detectContentChildrenChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19977:438
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19974:507
detectContentChildrenChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19977:438
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19974:507
detectViewChildrenChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19977:724
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19974:507
detectViewChildrenChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19977:724
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19974:507
detectContentChildrenChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19977:438
detectChangesInternal@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19977:98
detectChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19974:507
detectContentChildrenChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19977:438
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19974:507
detectViewChildrenChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19977:724
detectChangesInternal
detectChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:19974:507
detectChanges@http://localhost:3000/index.js:14295:1477
http://localhost:3000/index.js:8848:612
forEach@[native code]
tick@http://localhost:3000/index.js:8848:563
http://localhost:3000/index.js:8844:973
invoke@http://localhost:3000/index.js:27565:6355
onInvoke@http://localhost:3000/index.js:20266:1016
invoke@http://localhost:3000/index.js:27565:6265
run@http://localhost:3000/index.js:27565:2197
runInner@http://localhost:3000/index.js:20269:446
run@http://localhost:3000/index.js:9613:65
next@http://localhost:3000/index.js:8844:951
http://localhost:3000/index.js:9320:554
__tryOrUnsub@http://localhost:3000/index.js:980:1635
next@http://localhost:3000/index.js:980:767
_next@http://localhost:3000/index.js:975:293
next@http://localhost:3000/index.js:962:73
next@http://localhost:3000/index.js:1316:667
emit@http://localhost:3000/index.js:9320:178
_checkStable@http://localhost:3000/index.js:9574:44
onLeave@http://localhost:3000/index.js:9572:19
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:3000/index.js:20266:890
invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/index.js:27565:7121
runTask@http://localhost:3000/index.js:27565:3119
invoke@http://localhost:3000/index.js:27567:1046
    handleError (index.js:13885:483)
    next (index.js:8825:664)
    (anonymous function) (index.js:9320:555)
    __tryOrUnsub (index.js:980:1636)
    next (index.js:980:768)
    _next (index.js:975:294)
    next (index.js:962)
    next (index.js:1316:668)
    emit (index.js:9320:179)
    onError (index.js:9572:261)
    onHandleError (index.js:20269:272)
    handleError (index.js:27565:6501)
    runTask (index.js:27565:3198)
    invoke (index.js:27567:1047)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl
    __tryOrUnsub (index.js:980:1697)
    next (index.js:980:768)
    _next (index.js:975:294)
    next (index.js:962)
    next (index.js:1316:668)
    emit (index.js:9320:179)
    onError (index.js:9572:261)
    onHandleError (index.js:20269:272)
    handleError (index.js:27565:6501)
    runTask (index.js:27565:3198)
    invoke (index.js:27567:1047)
```

Turns out it is in Angular's common/bundles/common.umd.js, but it is undefined in Safari. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So ultimately the fix was to include Intl into the project:

```
npm install intl --save
```

In your main module:

```
import intl
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/nb';
```

The TypeError was due to trying to assign something to the (readonly)style property. See update above.

Comment: on that top import intl.  Is there a reason you did not end with a semi-colon?  I am seeing errors with and withou.